# ¿Como muestro en un Div una Imagen que esta en Base64?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo los datos binarios de la imagen en la base de datos y necesito mostrarla como una imagen por medio de un select y que me muestre la imagen en un div, Seria como descodificar la imagen que esta en base 64 a image para colocarla  vista de la pagina estoy utilizando asp.net C# con una arquitectura por N-capas

Comment: una imagen no se puede ver en un div, podrias verlo en un <img> de html

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas decodificar nada, la imagen asi como esta en base64 se puede mostrar sin problemas, el tag `img` de `html` lo soporta

[Embed Base64-Encoded Images Inline In HTML](http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html)

Como explica el articulo usas `data:image/png;base64` para definir el source, y alli nomas unes el `base64`

```
<img src=”data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS… (see source for full base64 
            encoded image) …8bgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=”>
```

[Embedding Images in HTML using C#](https://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/)

desde `asp.net` puede retornar la imagen encodeada a base64 para ubicarla en el img

Comment: Lo tengo de esta manera <code>MostrarImagen.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64,[Get_Enterate1.img_ent]";</code> ya no me aparece en el Div el mensaje que me aparecía antes de **System.Byte[]** me aparece el icono de que hay una imagen pero no se muestra la imagen,¿ que puede ser ?

Comment: porque no completas mejor la pregunta en ligar de abrir una nueva, se puede editar esta que ya tienes abierta

Comment: En el aspx lo tengo asi, no lo estoy mostrando en un Div lo estoy mostrando en un img asi ** <img runat="server" id="filepreview" src="">**

Comment: Veo extraño el uso de img con runat=server, con lo cual se trata de un HtmlImage, que es un Html Control, que pasa si usas un <asp:Image>

Comment: si inspeccionas el html que ves en el browser puedes observar que es correcto el src que asignaste? que pasa si tomas el base64 y lo conviertes a binario para generar el archivo, quizas no se este encodeando correctamente

Comment: podrias pegar aqui https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter  el base64 a ver si lo previsualizas